# Python MongoDB Dict Results?

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

Is there away to retrieve results from MongoDB in Python using PyMongo and have them in dict style? For example

```
    clogin = self.mdb.database.users.find_one( {"$and": [{"username" : str(username)},  {"password" : newpass}]})
    fname = clogin['First_name']
```

Comment: I think pymongo always return dict styles. They use dictionaries to represent documents: http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/tutorial.html#getting-a-single-document-with-find-one

Answer (score 2):

According to pymongo 2.0 [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/tutorial.html#getting-a-single-document-with-find-one):

> The most basic type of query that can be performed in MongoDB is
>   find_one(). This method returns a single document matching a query (or
>   None if there are no matches). It is useful when you know there is
>   only one matching document, or are only interested in the first match.
>   Here we use find_one() to get the first document from the posts
>   collection:

```
>>> posts.find_one()
{u'date': datetime.datetime(...), u'text': u'My first blog post!', u'_id': ObjectId('...'), u'author': u'Mike', u'tags': [u'mongodb', u'python', u'pymongo']}
```

> The result is a dictionary matching the one that we inserted
>   previously.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing would give you Dict Results. find_one() by pymongo returns results as dictionary. You may use clogin.get('First_name') to get result if exists or default to None if not.

find() would return a cursor so you might want to iterate over and get the results in the way you need.